# Cortar una string a partir de que aparezca un guión

Tags: javascript

Quiero que todas las strings que aparezcan con un guión dentro de ellas:

```
var ejemplo = "forty-six";
```

Sean cortadas a partir del guión, e idealmente con un método mutable que forme una variable nueva con lo que ha sido cortada después del guión. Es decir debería funcionar así:

`function cutString("forty-six") // Devuelve "six"` y la deja la variable ejemplo sólo con "forty":

```
ejemplo = "forty"
```

He probado con el **método slice** pero no veo como hacerlo ya que son varias strings y la longitud de estas cambia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La función que buscas es [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```js
var ejemplo = "forty-six";
var variable = ""

function cutString(string)
{ 
  var res = ejemplo.split("-");
  ejemplo= res[0];
  return res[1];
}

console.log(cutString(ejemplo));
console.log(ejemplo);
```